# SQL - How to get the word between special characters in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I am new to SQL and I would like to know how can I find the word between special characters? E.g I would like to get **gmail, yahoo** from **ram@gmail.com,ram@yahoo.com**

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle? (The answer will depend on which product you're using.)

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:
(for variables)

```
DECLARE @MAIL VARCHAR(200)='ram@gmail.com'
SET @MAIL=(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@MAIL),CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(@MAIL))+1,LEN(@MAIL)))
SELECT (SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@MAIL),CHARINDEX('@',REVERSE(@MAIL))+1,LEN(@MAIL)))
```

or 
(for column in table)

```
CREATE TABLE mails (MAIL VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO mails VALUES ('RAM@GMAIL.COM')
INSERT INTO mails VALUES ('RAM@YAHOO.COM')

SELECT SUBSTRING((SUBSTRING(MAIL,CHARINDEX('@',MAIL)+1,LEN(MAIL))),0,CHARINDEX('.',(SUBSTRING(MAIL,CHARINDEX('@',MAIL)+1,LEN(MAIL))))) FROM mails
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Oracle:

```
select regex_replace(email,'.*@([^\.]*).*)', '\1') from my_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use user defined function to split strings like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[str__split](
     @str           NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@delimiter     NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @split TABLE(
     [str] NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @split(
         [str]
    )
    SELECT 
        [X].[C].[value]('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
    FROM 
        ( 
            SELECT 
                [X] = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' + REPLACE(@str, @delimiter, '</i><i>') + '</i>').query('.')
        )                   AS  [A] 
    CROSS APPLY 
        [X].[nodes]('i')    AS  [X]([C]);

   RETURN;

END
```

And then get your data using query:

```
SELECT 
    LEFT([str], CHARINDEX('.', [str]) -1)  
FROM 
    [dbo].[str__split](@email, '@') 
WHERE  
        CHARINDEX('.', [str]) <>  0;
```

**You can use this in table query, not over one variable only.
Also, it works with multiple emails in one string(variable)**

Answer (score 0):

Hello There I believe that are business thing so you most likely to but it in the code section not in database section and you can handle it so fast so easy 
however

```
SELECT RIGHT(Email, LEN(Email) - CHARINDEX('@', email)) Domain ,
COUNT(Email) EmailCount 
FROM   dbo.email 
WHERE  LEN(Email) > 0
GROUP BY RIGHT(Email, LEN(Email) - CHARINDEX('@', email))
ORDER BY EmailCount DESC
```

and if you need more description you can find it on this site

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/06/18/sql-server-selecting-domain-from-email-address/

Answer (score 0):

Oracle

```
select regexp_substr(email,'@([^.]+)',1,1,'',1) from mytable
```